# no fontmanager in java.library.path

Tags: java, docker, jvm, headless, alpine-linux

The following code works just fine on my desktop:

```
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18));

        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.drawString(s, 5, 20);
```

However, when I run this code on my server (openjdk running on linux alpine within a Docker container), it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no fontmanager in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:339)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(SunFontManager.java:335)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:491)
at java.awt.Font.access$000(Font.java:224)
at java.awt.Font$FontAccessImpl.getFont2D(Font.java:228)
at sun.font.FontUtilities.getFont2D(FontUtilities.java:180)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.checkFontInfo(SunGraphics2D.java:669)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontInfo(SunGraphics2D.java:830)
at sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawString(GlyphListPipe.java:50)
at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.drawString(ValidatePipe.java:165)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(SunGraphics2D.java:2928)
```

java -version (on my server) gives:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_77-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-internal-alpine-r0-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

I searched for awt libs and they could be found here:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_headless.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem running Alpine Linux 3.4. I solved the problem by following the directions in [this github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/73):

1. Install the JRE with GUI support, i.e. `openjdk8-jre`
2. Install the `fontconfig` and `ttf-dejavu` packages

The RUN line in my Dockerfile looks like:

```
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre fontconfig ttf-dejavu
```

After this, the JDK was able to load the default fonts automatically, and the exception went away.

Comment: I tried using openjdk8-jre-base instead of openjdk8-jre, but it didn't work either.  Your answer is perfect, thank you!

Comment: I assume this should say `openjdk8-jre-headless`?

Comment: Instead of `openjdk8-jre-head`? Yes quite possibly, that might be a typo. Did a quick check and couldn't find `openjdk8-jre-head[less]` in the Alpine pkg repository so I'll remove that to  avoid confusion. AL 3.4 (and JDK8) is ancient now but in principal the answer probably applies to any Java 8 install on more recent Alpines, too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with my docker image for which I used Java 11 app base which does not have GUI libraries installed. I got the error like **no font manager** and the cause for that error is -> it is failing to read/create font using awt library.

When used the java stretch image with GUI support the error gone away.